# ionCube error when I make PHP code obfuscator on VScode(macOS M1, homebrew)

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, obfuscation, ioncube

As said on the title, I want to make code obfuscator for my coursework, but meet some problems when I want to use ionCube to code obfuscator.(the files hosts on localhost)

This is the error:
Site error: the ionCube PHP Loader needs to be installed. This is a widely used PHP extension for running ionCube protected PHP code, website security and malware blocking. Please visit get-loader.ioncube.com for install assistance.

I want to know what's the problem is? or if can't be solved, any other obfuscator tool recommand?

I will list my process on using ionCube blew.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I encode the PHP files, I choose 'Test encoding (Encoded download is FREE with 8 hour expiry)'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kTDU.png)
I download the encode files but not including 'Download Cost (5credits)' one

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6w75.png)
encode files can be shown on VS code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUvmF.jpg)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
donwload the 'macOS ARM M1 (arm64 64 bits)' 'zip'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otlNF.png)

unzip and find the file 'ioncube_loader_dar_8.2_ts.so' ('cause I use free-trial so choose end with ts one)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ior2w.png)

copy this file 'ioncube_loader_dar_8.2_ts.so' to PHP extension directory on path '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lognx.png)

add 'zend_extension = /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/ioncube_loader_dar_8.2_ts.so' to php.ini

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iA2M.png)
then restart PHP 'sudo brew services restart php@8.2', but the browser show the error.(my php file works, but encode php file don't work)

I want to know what's the problem is? or if can't be solved, any other obfuscator tool recommand?
I have two guess:
1.the free-trial support PHP 8.2, but my PHP is 8.2.11
(USER-GUIDE: The Loader for PHP 8.2 can only run files produced by the version 13 Encoder for PHP 8.2. Updates for any existing files produced for PHP 8.1 should be obtained to use them with PHP 8.2.)
2.the free-trial doesn't support the PHP files run on the serve project(even if localhost)

Comment: I have already solve the problem, I should use 'ioncube_loader_dar_8.2.so' but not 'ioncube_loader_dar_8.2_ts.so'. ts is Thread Safe, not test for free-trial here. I will keep the article for others

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.